# Host git server on windows 7

Tags: windows, git

I tried to follow [this guide](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH) to learn how to host a git server on windows, but i am currently stucked at this part of the guide:

> If you already have private and public keys, copy them to the
>   ...Program Files\ICW\home{username} folder and call them
>   {username}.key and {username}.key.pub. Also copy the public key to
>   ...ICW\home{username}.ssh\ and rename it to authorized_keys.

There is no folder called "ICW", where can i find it?

Comment: It's a conventional name for a cygwin root directory.

Comment: Ok, the article did not mentioned cygwin a single time, so the guide is obviously missing important informations. Can someone recommend me a good guide?

Comment: Do you mind me asking why you're trying to set up a git server on windows?

Comment: I try to host it to be able to work on a project with my team.

Comment: Is hosting it on Linux at all an option?  That gives you the ability to run something like [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/).  If your team is small enough, for 10 dollars you can also get [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server).